# scikit-learn train and test split returns NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

my sample data looks like below

```
customer_id   revenue_m10   revenue_m9   revenue_m8  target
   1             1234         1231        1256         1239
   2             5678         3425        3255         2345
```

I am trying to split my dataset into train and test based on scikit-learn's train_test_split module.

So, I tried the below code

```
X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(
    sample_set_df[all_features], 
    sample_set_df[target_var], 
    test_size=0.3
)
```

But when I view `y_test`, it looks like below with `NaNs` like below. Not sure what is the issue. Is the index number missing or any other issue?

if index is an issue, cam I know how can we solve this?

[image]

Comment: Without looking at the dataset its difficult to comment what is exactly happening. Is it possible for you to paste a sample of the data to make it reproducible?

Comment: @Indrajit - updated my data sample. It has 3 input features, 1 id column and 1 target column

Comment: These NaNs are in your dataset, not in the train_test_split function.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - But why is `y_test` showing two columns? because `y_test` has only one column of target values. Not sure why two columns are shown. Is the 1st one index column/

Comment: @TheGreat - Perform a `sample_set_df.reset_index(drop=True)` on your input data and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y_test` is a pandas Series, printing it displays its index and the data. It seems that `sample_set_df` has `NaNs` in its index.

Having `NaNs` in the index does not affect how `train_test_split` splits the data. You might have an issue with the actual data though. The target is 0 when you have `NaNs`.

Comment: can index be 0? what could be the reason why the index is 0? I obtain `sample_set_df` thorugh below code - `sample_set_df = features_df.merge(
    response_df, 
    left_index=True, 
    right_on='unique_key',
    how='left'
)

# Encode NaN values with 0.0
sample_set_df = sample_set_df.fillna(0)`

Comment: what do you think will be the correct way to merge?